# Power BI Public Embed URL filter

Tags: powerbi

I want to show a power bi report in a react app

But I want to use public url, I don't want to login to powerbi account.

and i want to filter a dataset with url

with the id of the logged in user

power bi public embed url filter possible? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the official documentation how to filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#considerations-and-troubleshooting), it is not supported:

> URL filters are supported in some embedding scenarios and not in others.
>
> - Embedding a report in a secure portal or website is supported.
> - URL filters are supported in Power BI Embedded. See Power BI Embedded advanced URL filtering capabilities for details.
> - **Query string filtering doesn't work with Publish to web or Export to PDF.**
> - Embed with report web part in SharePoint Online doesn't support URL filters.
> - Teams doesn't allow specifying a URL.

What you should do is to embed the report for your customers - see [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your customers application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-framework).